# Is it possible to put arithmetic expressions in a crontab?

Tags: shell, cron

I know I can do simple arithmetic in shell scripts, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
((sum = 1 + 2))
echo sum
```

This will output 3 on execution. My question now is, can this kind of expressions be used in crontab? For example, see this line:

```
03,13,23,33,43,53 * * * * ~/DoSomeStuff.sh
```

The minutes could be specified as `x+3` with `x` the expression `*/10`, which can be used in crontabs. However, simply writing `*/10+3` or `((*/10+3))` won't work. Is there any way to do this? And what is the correct syntax?

The alternative, that certainly works, is putting a `sleep 3m`. I'm just wondering if the arithmetic way of doing it is somehow possible.

Comment: You mean: x minutes after y?

Answer (score 7):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron):

> Slash ( / )
>
> Slashes describe increments of ranges. For example 3-59/15 in the 1st field (minutes) indicate the third minute of the hour and every 15 minutes thereafter. The form "*/..." is equivalent to the form "first-last/...", that is, an increment over the largest possible range of the field.

So `3-59/10 * * * * ~/DoSomeStuff.sh` should be what you're looking for.